# how can I get the width of the visible area of the view?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, view

I have a view which is bigger than the screen.

How can I get the width of its currently visible area?

`getWidth()` returns the absolut size.

Comment: if the view is bigger than the screen, woulsn't the screen size be the width visible?

Comment: right. but how i get this width?

Comment: I have answered, please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the screen width using the following code:

If you're calling this outside of an `Activity`, you'll need to pass the context in (or get it through some other call). Then use that to get your display metrics:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Using services you might do:

```
Display  display= ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth(); 
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Comment: how to get the context?

Comment: if outside of an activity then you have to send the context, if its inside then it is got by default.